# Keras fit ValueError in extremely simple test code

Tags: keras

I have encountered a very persistent problem in a more complex Keras program but have boiled it down to this: The answer must be very simple but I can't find it.

When I run this code:

```
def __init__ (self):
    self.model = Sequential()
    self.model.add(Dense(4, input_shape=(4,), activation='linear'))
    self.model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
def run(self):
    x = [1., 1., 1., 1.]
    print('x:', x, 'x shape:', np.shape(x))
    y = [0., 0., 0., 0.]
    print('y:', y, 'y shape:', np.shape(y))
    self.model.fit(x, y, batch_size=1, epochs=1, verbose=2)
```

The print statements show both x and y to be of shape (4,) but the fit line generates:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have
>   shape (4,) but got array with shape (1,)

I've tried reshaping `x` to (1,4) but it didn't help. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data should be 2D.
Make your x and y data as 2D by `x = [[1., 1., 1., 1.]]`. It becomes `1x4` data.
`1` is number of data and `4` is dimension what you define as the `input_shape`.
And, make it as numpy array by `x = np.array(x)`. Keras's `fit` method requires `numpy array`. I saw `x: Numpy array of training data` from https://keras.io/models/model/.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np

class A:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.model = Sequential()
        self.model.add(Dense(4, input_shape=(4,), activation='linear'))
        self.model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

    def run(self):
        x = [[1., 1., 1., 1.]]
        print('x:', x, 'x shape:', np.shape(x))
        y = [[0., 0., 0., 0.]]
        print('y:', y, 'y shape:', np.shape(y))
        x = np.array(x)
        y = np.array(y)
        self.model.fit(x, y, batch_size=1, epochs=1, verbose=2)

a = A()
a.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

the x and y arrays you pass are not the right shape. If you want to have input tensor of shape (4,) for your model then you have to prepare a tensor with shape (n,4) where n is the number of examples you are providing.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Dense


class Mymodel(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__ (self):
      super(Mymodel, self).__init__()
      self.model = Sequential()
      self.model.add(Dense(4, input_shape=(4,), activation='linear'))
      self.model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

  def run(self):
      x = np.ones((1,4))
      print('x:', x, 'x shape:', np.shape(x))
      y = np.zeros((1,4))
      print('y:', y, 'y shape:', np.shape(y))
      self.model.fit(x, y, batch_size=1, epochs=1, verbose=2)


model = Mymodel()
model.run()
```